# Switching key value pairs of a nested list only works for the first list

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple CLI hangman game which requires taking a raw input and checking a nested list for any matching pairs.

Here's the method that does the check:

```
def check_answer(guess):
    print gboard
    for k in gboard:
        if guess == k[0]:
            k[0],k[1] = k[1],k[0]
            print_board()
            promp_name()
        else:
            promp_name()
```

The method that makes gboard:

```
def generate_board():
    """ Makes the board """
    board = len(fword) 
    for i in range(board):
        gboard.append([fword[int(i)], '_'])
    print_board()
```

This will just make a list that looks something like:

```
gboard = [['p','_'],['y','_'],['t','_'],['h','_'],['o','_'],['n','_']]
```

The print board method simply prints the value pairs of gboard:

```
def print_board():
    final_layout = ''
    for key, value in gboard:
        final_layout+=value

    print final_layout
```

When the first value is guessed correctly: print_board does what it's supposed to do and returns the first letter uncovered:

```
p_____
```

The problem is when I guess anything beyond the first letter such as y. When that happens I'll get back:

```
p_____
```

as opposed to

```
py____
```

Basically the key/value pairs are only switched within the first list. Sorry for including so much code, I just don't know which part is the problem. Thanks!

EDIT: In case it matters, here's the prompt_name function:

```
def promp_name():
    user_input = raw_input("Enter a letter: \n")
    user_input = user_input.lower()
    user_guess(user_input)
```

user_guess just validates the guess then calls check_answer:

user_guess(input)

Also, gboard is a global variable defined in the main class

Comment: What is 'promp_name()' function ?

Comment: gboard is a global variable?

Comment: It takes a raw input and calls check answer with the input. check_answer's parameter takes this raw input and uses it. I'll just include it in as an edit since it's so short

Comment: yes it is @selllikesybok

Comment: It'd be useful to see the flow into / out of check_answer. My suspicion is your control flow is jacked up somehow.

Comment: What happens if your first guess is 'y', in this example? Same issue?

Comment: Yes. Only the first value uncovers despite which guess it is. Would it be helpful to include the function that validates the guess (and also calls check_answer) @selllikesybok

Comment: I think you're better off posting the whole thing, at this point. Seems like you have multiple problems.

Comment: Turns out it was my recursive calling. The else case was limited to only the first letter because it was repeatedly being called on the first iteration. That's my understanding anyways. Thanks for the help @selllikesybok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the issue is in the else part . If you find the first element in gboard to be a mismatch , the else part is run which recursively calls check_answer() after getting input , so it only ever checks the first element in the gboard list.

You most probably do not want to execute the else part until you are sure none of the letters in gboard match . So you want to move the code in else part outside the loop and maybe use a flag to indicate whether to run it or not (that is a flag to indicate whether there were any matches or not) .

---

From the comments it looks like you are doing a recursive method , if so you need to make sure you return after calling promp_name() (if you are retuning you do not need the flag). Example -

```
def check_answer(guess):
    print gboard
    for k in gboard:
        if guess == k[0]:
            k[0],k[1] = k[1],k[0]
            print_board()
            return promp_name()
    return promp_name()
```

Comment: This was my thinking as well.

Comment: Little confusing, but it worked as expected. Thanks for the help both of you